# With SQL Server 2022+ Do I Have To Migrate Code Away From SqlConnection Class Objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-2022

**EDIT: I understand the migration from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` for newer .NET projects. What I am failing to understand is how the `*.Data.SqlClient` namespace communicates with SQL Server. This question comes to mind considering that Microsoft has now deprecated one of its clients, the SQL Native Client (SNAC).**

**i.e.** How does the `*.Data.SqlClient` namespace communicate with SQL Server 2022 databases? Do developers need to worry about their codebase with the announcement of the deprecation of SQL Native Client?

---

Coding in C# and using a Microsoft SQL Server back-end, we are currently migrating databases from SQL Server 2019 to the newer SQL Server 2022 environment. Our codebase explicitly uses `SqlConnection` objects from the `System.Data.SqlClient` or newer `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

According to Microsoft's website, the [SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) is now deprecated in SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16). Will our codebase need to be migrated away from using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` objects (or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`) in order to continue to function with newer SQL Server 2022(+) instances?

Example connection string:

```
<add name="myConnection" 
     connectionString="Server=DEV-SQLSERVER2019-01.mycompany.local,1433;TrustServerCertificate=True;Database=Tokens;User ID=TokensApp;Password=ABC123"  
     providerName="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Example code:

```
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

private static string CreateToken(string code, string email)
{
    string token;

    try 
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString)) 
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand()) 
            {
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "spCreateToken";
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Token", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = NEW_GLOBAL_TOKEN();
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 6).Value = code.ToUpper();
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value = email.ToLower();

                token = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException exSQL) when (exSQL.Message.Contains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint")) 
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("This email address '{0}' has already been sent an invitiation.", email));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex.Message.Equals("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.")) 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("The email address provided '{0}' has already signed-up.", email));
    }

    return token;
}
```

If this codebase does need to be changed—How should I go about interfacing Microsoft SQL Server 2022+ databases within my C# codebase with regards to:

- Connection string format
- Database connection class type
- Database command class type
- Individual database object type(s)
- Individual database exception class type(s)
- Database transaction class type(s)
- SQL Server database user-defined values / table-valued parameter type(s)

I've read the deprecation changes coming to the new SQL Server 2022, but I am confused as to If or How this will actually affect our codebase that uses C# and explicitly calls the `SqlConnection` class to connect to our Microsoft SQL Server databases. It looks as though the migration path, if necessary, will be cumbersome to ensure proper functionality using a new SQL client object type.

Comment: Please show "using" statements in your c# code, and show the important parts (package-references) of your csproj.

Comment: SQL Server Native Client has nothing to do with SqlClient in C#. Also `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is already the latest version, but `System.Data.SqlClient` will continue being supported. Further help here https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/porting-cheat-sheet.md

Comment: @Charlieface thank you, can you please explain how they are different? I am confused as to what this means from a developer standpoint explicitly using the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` class library.

Comment: It means that the old one won't be extended anymore and the new one will.  So, you will want to migrate to the newer one and use it going forward for new engineering and upgrade existing clients when you can properly do a test run to validate things are working correctly with the new client driver.

Comment: @Conor thank you, I understand the migration from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. My misunderstanding comes when implementing connections from code to the MSSQL 2022+ databases. With the SQL Native Client being deprecated; will this affect my codebase that uses `SqlConnection` class objects? Why or Why Not?

Comment: Again nothing to do with it. We don't need to explain why, you need to explain why you think it's relevant. it's just chalk and cheese, apples and oranges, a non-sequitur. It's completely totally utterly absolutely irrelevant to the conversation, it has no bearing on it, it's in another world. In C#, forget you ever heard of Native Client, it's not for you. All you need to worry about is `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` or the older but still supported `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: In case you wanted a little more information: SqlClient uses a library called SNI.dll which is a native C library internally used by Microsoft (no published docs), it is entirely separate from the Native Client ODBC driver, which is designed to be used by any code supporting ODBC, and is fully documented.

Comment: @Charlieface thank you again. Can you please rephrase your latest comment into a response that I can mark as Answered? Apologies to you/others for not being able to better distinguish my lack of knowledge between the `SqlClient` codebase on the developer-side and the SQL Native Client on the server-side; and wrongly conflating the two.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL Server Native Client has ***absolutely*** nothing to do with SqlClient in C#. It's an ODBC driver which is used by C/C++ and other tools which utilize ODBC.

It's just chalk and cheese, apples and oranges, a non-sequitur. It's completely, totally, utterly and absolutely irrelevant to the conversation, it has no bearing on it, it's in another world. In C#, forget you ever heard of Native Client, it's not for you.

All you need to worry about is `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` or the older but still supported `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Now that you've purported there exists a clear difference between the `*.Data.SqlClient` library and the SQL Native Client driver—Can you please explain the Who/What/Where/When/Why they are different?

Comment: Honestly I don't know why you keep bringing this up. The Native Client driver is for ODBC compatible tools such as pyodbc and C++. SqlClient is written in C#, and is for use by .Net applications written in C#, VB, F# etc. Different drivers for different things, written in different languages for different users. I just don't get why you have in your head that Native Client should even be relevant if you are using SqlClient. It's like saying "does this Linux tool being deprecated affect my Windows installation?"

Comment: I am looking to receive context to the differences. Something to the effect of ".NET SqlClient is meant for .NET developers and communicates with MSSQL servers via A/B/C means; this is in stark contrast to the purpose of the Sql Native Client driver which is meant for (?) and communicates via X/Y/Z means." Expanding on this context, does the SqlClient interface with _any_ of the drivers that are referenced in the Sql Server docs (Native, ODBC, old MSOLEDBSQL, new MSOLEDBSQL19) or is it completely separate?

Comment: Completely separate. It uses an internal DLL called sni.dll which is separate from the ODBC and OLEDB drivers you mention.